# Adding first column of many dataframes to new dataframes in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a list of 17 dataframes. From this list, i want to "select" the first column for every dataframe and place it into a new dataframe. The wanted result would be that there is created several new dataframes. e.g. the first resulting dataframe contains all first columnn of all 17 dataframes. the second resulting dataframe contains the second column of all 17 dataframes.

I will show you a visual representation of what i want below[image]

I really hope you can help me out with this!

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you would like to grab the first column of each data frame in a list and turn that into a data frame, then do the same for the second column of each data frame, etc. until you reach the last column of each data frame. I'm assuming each data frame has the same dimensions.

Here's a `base` solution using nested `lapply` functions. The output is a list of n `data.frame`, where n is the number of columns in your data frames.

In my example, the list has four data frames of three columns each. Therefore, the output contains three data frames of four columns each.

```
lapply(1:ncol(l[[1]]), function(y) as.data.frame(sapply(l, function(x) x[, y])))

[[1]]
  V1 V2 V3 V4
1  1  1  1  1
2  2  2  2  2
3  3  3  3  3
4  4  4  4  4
5  5  5  5  5

[[2]]
  V1 V2 V3 V4
1  2  2  2  2
2  3  3  3  3
3  4  4  4  4
4  5  5  5  5
5  6  6  6  6

[[3]]
  V1 V2 V3 V4
1  3  3  3  3
2  4  4  4  4
3  5  5  5  5
4  6  6  6  6
5  7  7  7  7
```

Sample data:

```
l <- list(data.frame(a = c(1:5), b = c(2:6), c = c(3:7)), data.frame(a = c(1:5), b = c(2:6), c = c(3:7)), data.frame(a = c(1:5), b = c(2:6), c = c(3:7)), data.frame(a = c(1:5), b = c(2:6), c = c(3:7)))
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I needed. This works like a charm. Thanks a lot! merry x-mas and a happy new year in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Using `purrr::map_dfc`

```
library(purrr)
lst<-list(iris, iris)
fstcol <- map_dfc(lst, ~dplyr::select(.x, 1) %>% head)
sndcol <- map_dfc(lst, ~dplyr::select(.x, 2) %>% head)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to transpose the data in a list of `k` data frames each of dimension `n` rows times `m` columns into a list of `m` data.frames each of dimension `n` rows times `k` columns.

The list of data frames

```
lst <- rep(list(mtcars[1:4, 1:5]), 3L)
lst
```

> ```
> [[1]]
>                 mpg cyl disp  hp drat
> Mazda RX4      21.0   6  160 110 3.90
> Mazda RX4 Wag  21.0   6  160 110 3.90
> Datsun 710     22.8   4  108  93 3.85
> Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6  258 110 3.08
>
> [[2]]
>                 mpg cyl disp  hp drat
> Mazda RX4      21.0   6  160 110 3.90
> Mazda RX4 Wag  21.0   6  160 110 3.90
> Datsun 710     22.8   4  108  93 3.85
> Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6  258 110 3.08
>
> [[3]]
>                 mpg cyl disp  hp drat
> Mazda RX4      21.0   6  160 110 3.90
> Mazda RX4 Wag  21.0   6  160 110 3.90
> Datsun 710     22.8   4  108  93 3.85
> Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6  258 110 3.08
> ```

is transformed by

```
library(magrittr)
purrr::transpose(lst) %>% 
  lapply(data.table::as.data.table)
```

into

> ```
> $mpg
>      V1   V2   V3
> 1: 21.0 21.0 21.0
> 2: 21.0 21.0 21.0
> 3: 22.8 22.8 22.8
> 4: 21.4 21.4 21.4
>
> $cyl
>    V1 V2 V3
> 1:  6  6  6
> 2:  6  6  6
> 3:  4  4  4
> 4:  6  6  6
>
> $disp
>     V1  V2  V3
> 1: 160 160 160
> 2: 160 160 160
> 3: 108 108 108
> 4: 258 258 258
>
> $hp
>     V1  V2  V3
> 1: 110 110 110
> 2: 110 110 110
> 3:  93  93  93
> 4: 110 110 110
>
> $drat
>      V1   V2   V3
> 1: 3.90 3.90 3.90
> 2: 3.90 3.90 3.90
> 3: 3.85 3.85 3.85
> 4: 3.08 3.08 3.08
> ```

`as.data.table()` is used here because it names the columns automatically.

Comment: Another solution, and I tested it and it also works. Thank you very much for your help. merry x-mas and a happy new year in advance